# @ prefix when setting environment variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

Here is what I've got so far:

```
SPECS = $(shell find spec -iname "*_spec.js")

spec:
    @NODE_ENV=test \
    @NODE_PATH=lib \
    ./node_modules/.bin/expresso \
    $(TESTFLAGS) \
    $(SPECS)

cov:
    @TESTFLAGS=--cov $(MAKE) spec

.PHONY: spec cov
```

Output: `/bin/sh: @NODE_PATH=lib: command not found`

If I set one variable only it's working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use '@' only once.  It is only needed at the very beginning of the string, but you have it twice.  The line continuations are very literal, and your current code reads:

```
@NODE_ENV=test @NODE_PATH=lib ./node_modules/.bin/expresso $(TESTFLAGS) $(SPECS)
```

The '@' on NODE_PATH is getting passed to the shell, which you do not want.