# settings environment in makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to export an env variable in make to use in on the next lines. I am doing as suggested here [Setting environment variables in a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27282660/setting-environment-variables-in-a-makefile).

```
eks-apps:
    export KUBECONFIG=$(CURDIR)/terraform/kubernetes/cluster/$(shell ls terraform/kubernetes/cluster/ | grep kubeconfig)
    kubectl get all
```

But its not using that kubeconfig in the kubectl command. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every line in a recipe will be executed in a new shell. As this you have to use a single shell for all your commands:

```
eks-apps:
    ( \
    export KUBECONFIG=$(CURDIR)/terraform/kubernetes/cluster/$(shell ls terraform/kubernetes/cluster/ | grep kubeconfig); \
    kubectl get all \
    )
```

From the answer you are linked to:

> Please note: this implies that setting shell variables and invoking shell commands such as cd that set a context local to each process will not affect the following lines in the recipe.2 If you want to use cd to affect the next statement, put both statements in a single recipe line

Comment: But this is explicitly what the linked answer is claiming is not required.

Comment: Ah no, I i think I misread that. You are right.

Comment: This will work fine but a few notes: You don't need the `( ... )` around the command because every line already runs in a shell, and you should probably prefer using `&&` between your commands instead of `;` so that if the first line fails it won't try to run the next one.