# Setting environment variable in makefile and reading it from python script does not work

Tags: python, bash, makefile, environment-variables

I am setting a environment variable (bash) in makefile and I am executing a python script on the next line in the makefile. However, when I try to read the environment variable in the python script using `os.environ.get()` I am unable to read the environment variable. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a MCVE.

Comment: Are you `export`ing the variable? As in:  `export MYVAR=1234`

Comment: @AustinHastings, yes.

Comment: Does the previous line end with a semicolon and a backslash, like `export MYVAR=1234 ; \\ `

Comment: @AustinHastings. Here is the makefile snippet "export ABC=$(XYZ)" followed by the call to execute the python script. No, there is no semi-colon, nor a backslash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting environment variable in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8022586/608639)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to export it in the same line:

```
target:
        export FOO=bar; python /the/script.py
```

or

```
target:
        export FOO=bar; \
        python /the/script.py
```

Comment: Your adviced helped me a lot! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my system.

makefile

```
ENVVAR=10
export ENVVAR

run:
    python script.py
```

script.py

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('ENVVAR'))
```

running:

```
$ ls
makefile script.py
$ make
python script.py
10
```