# How to export environment variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables

I'm trying to export environment variables so that they can be accessed in the parent shell
MakeFile:

```
export-vars:
    # extract vars from text file - remove comments - export output
    export $$(cat env.txt | grep -v ^# | xargs)
```

Then when I run:

```
$ make export-vars
$ echo $SOME_VAR_EXPORTED_FROM_MAKEFILE
```

I am expecting the vars in the text to be set as environment vars.

Any help how to do this within a target/rule?

Comment: Make isn't a good tool for this. Would you consider a shell script?

Comment: @Beta I would consider it. Would I be able to create commands from a shell script similar to Make?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Beta Sorry, let me clarify, you are asking me if I would consider a shell script, correct?

Comment: Yes, and you said you would. Then you asked whether you could use a script similar to Make to create commands; or maybe whether you could create a script that accepts arguments the way Make does; or maybe whether you could create a script that invokes Make. (The answer to all three is "yes".)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting environment variable in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8022586/608639)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do this with a makefile OR with a separate shell script.  When you run make, or run a shell script, it creates a new process.  Any changes made to the environment of that process will all be tossed away when that process exits.  It's not possible (in a UNIX-like system) for a process to modify the environment of its *parent* process.

The only thing you can do is either write a shell function, which is invoked within the shell process you're running (which is displaying your prompt, etc.) or have a script that you source, not run: that will cause the script to run in the same shell process rather than creating a new one.

So you could write a shell function in your `~/.bashrc` or similar like this:

```
setvars () { export $(grep -v ^# env.txt | xargs); }
```

Or you could write a separate shell script, but you can't run it you have to source it (the `.` command sources a script rather than running it):

```
. set-my-vars.sh
```