# Reading dotenv file within a target in a Makefile

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, environment-variables, gnu-make

I have a Makefile such that one of the targets creates a `.env` file, which is read in another target.
So, since the file is created dynamically, I can't `include` it at the top of the Makefile. I tried the method using `export` and `xargs`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381310/how-to-export-environment-variables-in-makefile), but it doesn't work. Here's my Makefile:

```
create_dotenv_file:
  echo "FOO=BAR" > .env

test_env: create_dotenv_file
  export $(cat .env | xargs) && \
  echo $(FOO)
```

And this is what I get when executing `$ make test_env`:

```
/home# make test_env
echo "FOO=BAR" > .env
export  && \
echo
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do but, the statement `"since the file is created dynamically, I can't include it at the top of the Makefile"` is incorrect -- makefiles can be [remade](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles).

Comment: What I mean is that the `.env` file doesn't exist when the Makefile is called, so it's pointless to use `include .env`. Now I'm not sure what you mean: are all the commands in a Makefile are executed for every target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. the expression `$(cat .env | xargs)`  isn't doing what you intend. The `make` command itself uses `$` to variable expansion; this means that `make` is interpreting that expression, rather than the shell. To `make` it looks like a reference to an invalid variable so the replacement is the empty string.

   Similarly, `$(FOO)` is referring to the `make` variable `FOO`, which doesn't exist.

   You will need to replace `$` with `$$` in order for the shell to see a single `$`.
2. Each **line** in a Makefile target executes in a new shell. Even if your `export $(cat .env|xargs)` statement works, it's a no-op -- changes to environment variables only impact the current process and its children. You are effectively starting a new shell, setting an environment variable, and then exiting the shell; your environment variables are lost.

---

You can rewrite your `Makefile` so that it "works" by doing something like this:

```
create_dotenv_file:
    echo "FOO=1" > .env
    echo "BAR=2" >> .env

test_env: create_dotenv_file
    export $$(xargs < .env); \
    echo $${FOO}
```

But this is still problematic. The above sets two variables and works as expected, but what happens if one of your variables contains whitespace, like:

```
create_dotenv_file:
    echo "FOO=\"This is \"" > .env
    echo "BAR=\"a test\"" >> .env
```

You'll end up with the shell expression:

```
export FOO=This is  BAR=a test
```

So you will have `FOO=This`, `BAR=a`, and a couple of empty environment variables named `is` and `test`.

A more effective solution might look something like this:

```
create_dotenv_file:
    echo "FOO=\"This is \"" > .env
    echo "BAR=\"a test\"" >> .env

test_env: create_dotenv_file
    set -a; \
    . ./.env; \
    set +a; \
    echo $${FOO}
```

This uses `set -a` to enable the `export` of all variables that we create or modify; then `.` to read in the `.env` file, and then `set +a` to disable the `set -a`. The output of running `make test_env` with the above `Makefile` is:

```
echo "FOO=\"This is \"" > .env
echo "BAR=\"a test\"" >> .env
set -a; \
. ./.env; \
set +a; \
echo ${FOO}
This is
```

---

But even with that solution, it probably still doesn't do what you want...variables sourced in the `test_env` target won't be available anywhere else, because setting environment variables only impacts the current process and its children. Exporting variables in shell scripts simply cannot make them available elsewhere in the `Makefile`.

Comment: LOL! You were far more patient than I would have been had I written an answer. I'll point out that many of the problems you noted are due to the POSIX 1003.2 standard. I started programming in 1977 and used my first UNIX system around 1983 so I've got decades of experience with these types of issues. While I think Windows has even more problems it is a shame we're still dealing with the bogosities of the POSIX 1003.2 standard.